# Синтаксическая ошибка при декодировании json (ajax, php)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Отправляю строку json строку на сервер:

```
    var data = {};
    $('#block-new17 .cont').each(function(e, i) {
        var v1 = $(this).attr('data-mapping');
        var v2 = $(this).find('input, textarea').val();
        data[v1] = v2;
    });
    data['title'] = $('#block-new16 span:last').text();
    var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "someurl.php",
        data: 'jsonData=' + dataJSON,
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log('false');
        }
    });
```

На сервер приходит все ок, json

```
{"uname":"ntcwerwer","uphone":" 7 (234) 323-33-33","title":"Получить бесплатный каталог"}
```

При декодировании выдает ошибку в синтаксисе.
Думал дело в кавычках - добавил:

```
$json = "'" . $_POST['jsonData'] . "'";
```

не помогло. Причем такой вариант работает:

```
 $json = '{"uname":"ntcwerwer","uphone":" 7 (234) 323-33-33","title":"Получить бесплатный каталог"}';
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

А вот строка с $_POST - нет.

Comment: Вопрос а зачем в загонять в `JSON` если `$.ajax({data:})` можно скормит массив и потом к его элементам обращатья?

Comment: @E_p в данном случае может не страшно, но в общем, бывает на столько большой объем данных, что сервер выдаст фаталочку из-за превышения передаваемых данных в запросе `php max input vars`

Comment: @Maks Devda Можете показать действительно то, что отображается в консоли браузера при отправке данных?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если есть такая проблема, то проблема в архитектуре. Автор что то скрывает. Прогнал с его данными работает на 5+ :)

Comment: Ну решил сам. Пришлось добавлять stripslashes. 
Код такой вышел `$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonData']), true);`

@E_p параметров может быть как и 2 так и 20 поэтому пробегал по полях и загонял в JSON. Можно было сделать по другому, но это для интеграции lpgenerator - а там машинный код генерирует конструктор. Приходится писать костили

Comment: @E_p конечно скрывает. все почему-то донельзя упрощают код, думая что так лучше, при этом сама ошибка скрывается в том, что автор не указал в полной мере. и мы сидим тут телепатим.......... между тем автор указал как решил проблему..... и да. это наверняка связано с тем, что не показал нам все пересылаемые данные

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский ребят я ничего не скрывал. Показал все как и есть. Заработало как только добавил stripslashes.

Какую часть кода Вам показать еще ? Мне просто интересно почему такой глюк.

Comment: Так ради интереса какие параметры в ПХП выставлены для http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php. get_magic_quotes_gpc() Что возврашает? На странице есть пример как чистить. (Сюрприз в том что чистят stripslashes) :).

Comment: @MaksDevda нужно видеть точно что вы передаете (что отображается в браузере при передаче), какую именно синтаксическую ошибку выкидывает и что там написано.. это бывает по многим причинам. самое очевидное что формируется невалидный json. может там в тексте теги, слеши,

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет там чистый json точно. Я не начинающий программист просто с таким впервые столкнулся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно покурив мануал пришел к выводу:

1. magic_quotes_gpc включен, у автора ПХП < 5.4. (ПХП 5.4+ ни кто ни когда не словил бы эту
   ошибку так как деррективу убрали).
   http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc
2. Лучшее решение обновить ПХП/отключить деррективу.
3. Как вариант можно исползовать код из
   http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php. Что бы
   чистить все массивы сразу:

Code:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

ПС: Смотрите `stripslashes`  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну решил сам. Пришлось добавлять stripslashes. Код такой вышел `$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonData']), true);`